Can't remove liquidity from Uniswap V2 LP. Worked before i renounce ownership
after having a test about doing a token for our stream with a friends and despite the fact the liquidity was locked and i renounced the smartcontract there was no appeal for the project. I would like to now to take my ETH back but it's not working anymore, i've tried to increase my slippage up to 40%, reduced every token amount to 1 because i added a buy & sell fee.
Look like Token not tradable with uniswap interface but some bot still bought as i saw on Dextools
Any way to retrieve the liquidity from the back end smart contract or something ?
Here is the contract link :
https://basescan.org/address/0x367b1061c861771ca610e9ef1bc5b909da353b8b#writeContract
Thanks for your time :)

Fails at super._transfer(sender, owner(), tax); with ERC20: transfer to the zero address. Trying to send the tax to the zero address after having burned ownership. While having erc 20 mechanics that don't allow that require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");. Think if cannot turn tax off or change owner it might be stuck.

Okay noted ! Still a good way to learn lmao. Thanks your times !

Oh yes it's the best way to learn in terms of having the lesson stay with you. Great attitude. As long as stick with it and learn form it, you can make it back in this space easily.
